# Threads and event handling in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, event-handling

I am a Java newbie and an Android newbie too. I am working on a game and trying to understand the exact nature of events in Java and Android. I have a few questions to help understand the correct way to do event handling in my app.

Its a network game and so I need to check if the user made a move or not to update the view. Also I need to prompt the user to make a move if he takes too long. For this I have two threads -

- Timer thread expires every 10 seconds and calls updateview if needed or prompts user to make a move.
- Event thread gets created when user clicks on the screen to make a move or clicks on menu etc.

Is this the correct approach? These two can be fired at any time.

Here are the issues I see with this -

- What happens when one thread gets run when the other one is active.
- Which thread has precedence if both are started at the same time.
- Do events in the timer thread get queued up?
- If so can I pick which one in the queue to use?
- Can I cancel events in the queue? For e.g. if I have 2 updateview events lined up in the queue I only have to call it once.

Thanks for any inputs.

P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest reading up on Android [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am reading through this and will see how to use it.

Comment: Thanks AsyncTask is very good. I also learned some very useful things about threads and UI threads in Android in general while reading about AsyncTasks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you can implement a timer WiTHOUT using a thread. Use a single Handler switching on what and send a postMessageDelayed(what 0,milliseconds) to the handler say every one second. You could set a counter variable to zero and check the flag every one second in the what 0 handler, incrementing the counter by one. If the value is >= ten, post a message and reset the variable to zero. If the user selects an action, reset the instance variable to zero.

A time consuming action can be run in a separate thread that messages the handler, perhaps using what 1, on completion. Or you could run a time consuming action in a separate asyncTask.

JAL

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will try to do it this way and see how it goes.